# Anyone know how to integrate angular-dynamic-locale with webpack

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, webpack

I'm fairly new to using webpack and I seem to be having problems trying to get angular-dynamic-locale working in webpack

I executed

```
npm install angular-dynamic-locale
```

placed this in my entry file.

```
var dynamicLocale = require('angular-dynamic-locale');
module.exports = angular.module('app', [dynamicLocale])
.config(function(tmhDynamicLocale){});
```

I keep getting "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tmhDynamicLocale"

any help is greatly apprecited

Answer (score 1):

never mind. i figured it out, it was something silly.

instead of:

```
  .config(function(tmhDynamicLocale){});
```

i used

```
.run(function(tmhDynamicLocale){});
```

it works